# Image with position:absolute not centering inside parent div with position:relative

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First, not sure if it is relevant or not, but I'm using Bootstrap 3.

So for this section of my page (there's more below it) I have the viewport height set to 100, and inside it are two rows that each take up 50% of that viewport. In the first row is an image that I'm trying to center both horizontally and vertically. In the second row is an image that I'm trying to center horizontally and be fixed to the bottom. The html looks like this:

```html
<div class='row vh-100'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 height-100'>

        <!-- tats -->
        <div class='row height-50'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 relative height-100'>
                <img src='images/logo.png' 
                     class='img-responsive block absolute center middle max-height-100'>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- silhouette -->
        <div class='row height-50'>
            <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 relative height-100'>
                <img src='images/silhouette.png' 
                     class='img-responsive block absolute center bottom max-height-100'>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```css
.block{
 display: block;
}

.absolute{
 position: absolute;
}

.relative{
 position: relative;
}

.vh-100{
 height: 100vh;
}

.vh-50{
 height: 50vh;
}

.height-100{
 height: 100%;
}

.height-50{
 height: 50%;
}

.center{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.top{
 top: 0%;
}

.middle{
 top: 50%;
}

.bottom{
 bottom: 0%;
}

.max-height-100{
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

So what I'm running into is this: neither image centers horizontally unless I change their position to relative. Also, the first image centers vertically inside the whole page, not the div its contained in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

absolute position elements are centered like this:

```
#element {
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

(don't forget to add vendors for the transform: -webkit-transform, etc)

Also if you know the width of the absolute element, you can use:

```
margin-left:-halfelemwidth;
margin-top:-halfelemheight;
```

This will help with support for older browsers that do not support css transforms

**edit:** too tired when typed, was brought to my attention by user below that the margin-top and margin-left should be half instead of full.

**edit2:** you can also try this approach.

For the **parent** element with the height use:

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
```

This can center the images without leaving the container, and without relative and absolute elements.

Comment: Should probably be `margin-left: -(half-width)`

Comment: Thanks! That solved the horizontal centering. However, the top image is still centered vertically for the the entire page. It should be centered vertically in the top half, as its parent element only takes up 50% of the page.

Comment: I cant see anything on the snippet..is it just me?